# What does "from the safety of a shelter" mean in this context?

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

> Hong Kong is traditionally a sought-after destination for domestic workers because of the relatively high wages offered, a guaranteed rest day once a week and other legal protections not offered in other places. But, says Rohyati, just two weeks into her job as a full-time, live-in maid, her employer's mother slapped her because the elderly woman, who spoke only Cantonese, was frustrated at being unable to communicate. Over the next two months, she says she was slapped, punched and choked by her boss as well. "I don't know why she hit me. At times she seemed to care about my welfare. She **would** ask if I was comfortable or had enough to eat," said Rohyati. "But she **would** suddenly turn violent. Maybe she was feeling overworked, or upset about still being single," **she recalls from the safety of a shelter run by a charity**.

http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-china-27184521

She was told to go back to her previous job that they had provided for her? Is
*safety of a shelter* correct? And why do they say "from"?

What time the does *would* refer to? A habitual action in the past? That is to say, was it her boss's habit *in the past* or *now* to ask if she had been comfortable?

When the girl says her boss that is a single woman and would turn violent, does it mean that there were regular times in the past that her boss had become angry? Or could it mean that her boss still might become angry?

Our assumption is that of course she is still her boss, but when we are talking about past and complete actions in the past, we usually use simple past, as *used to* or *had been*. What about the word *would*?

Comment: Good question. In storytelling, *would* is quite commonly used to describe the regular action - *he **would** sit at the river bank whenever sad.* *From* shows the reason of that judgement (OALD #13) I guess. 'Safety of a shelter' is questioning the safety where she took the shelter.

Comment: *Would* here is equivalent to *used to*.

Comment: @MaulikV I agree with your analysis of 'would', but I'm not sure I understand what you're saying "safety of a shelter" means.  There is no question there, only that the woman is recalling (remembering and telling) the events from a shelter, which is safe (as opposed to the abusive workplace she's talking about) which is run by a charity (an organization which seeks to help people in need).

Comment: @Doc is correct. "**she recalls**" = she is remembering or recounting the events. "**from the safety of a shelter**" = she is in a _shelter_ as she is telling her story, which is a safe place for her. "**run by a charity**" = the shelter is run by a non-profit charity organization.

Answer (score 12):

That last line says the following:

- [*she recalls*] the girl is remembering this as she is talking
- [*from ... a shelter*] she is in a shelter while she is talking
- [*safety*] the shelter is a safe place
- [*run by a charity*] the shelter is being run by a charity

To recall in this case means remembering something. Since the article reports her words, the verb *recall* is used here as "remember while talking".

A shelter is a place where one can hide from the weather, or from other people. In this case it is a place where women like this girl can be safe after having been mistreated by their employers.

A charity is an organisation that tries to help people without expecting to get any money from it. In this case, it mean that a well-fare organisation is providing people to take care of the day-to-day business of managing the shelter.

---

As for the use of would, yes, that indicates a habitual action in the past. It doesn't seem that the girl is still working there, she went to the shelter instead. So whether or not the habitual action continues into the present is not relevant for that girl or for this girl's story.

Comment: +1  But, for the sake of clarity, could you add to your answer what each of the bulleted points is derived from in the quote?  As in "The girl is remembering this as she is talking" is based on "she recalls", "she is in a shelter while she is talking" is based on "from [...] a shelter", etc.  At least define recall (as it has multiple definitions that may cause confusion) and maybe shelter.

Comment: Good points, I edited :)

Comment: Awesome. I'd give you another +1 if I could for the edit.

Comment: I'd suggest that a clearer definition of 'she recalls' might be 'the girl is talking about an event that she remembers'.  +1 all around, though.

Answer (score 2):

"Recall" is meaning #1 at this dictionary link: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/recall meaning to bring back from memory.

A "shelter" in this case refers to a refuge for people in unfortunate circumstances; such as a "homeless shelter" or a "shelter for abused women."

Answer (score 0):

The word "would" could be switched with "sometimes", or the phrase "had been known to".
The last sentence gives the impression that the character Rohyati left her employment because of the abuse, and went to a charity-run shelter. I imagine that Rohyati herself did not speak Cantonese at all. I suppose that the old woman asked about her welfare hoping Rohyati would stay. No feelings of genuine concern.